# Reset page to initial state qml

Tags: qt, properties, qt4, qml

I'm using this code to load a page

```
            onClicked:
            {
                creationDetailsSheetLoader.source = "CreationDetailsPage.qml"
                creationDetailsSheetLoader.item.reset()
                pageStack.push(creationDetailsSheetLoader.item)
            }
```

I'd like to have the data

```
property string iconPath: ""
property string iconName: ""
property string appNameString: ""
property string desktop: ""
```

reset after each exit from the page

I have components properties set this way

```
                text: ( desktop == "" ) ? "No app selected" : desktop
```

If I do

```
function reset()
{
    iconName = ""
    iconPath = ""
    appNameString = ""
    desktop = ""
}
```

and call this onLoaded of the loader, the component properties, as the above specified stay the same
What am I doing wrong?
Or is there any easy way of resetting the page to the initial state

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I removed the property binding, like that

```
entryName.text = "somestring"
```